# What are the uses for custom linker scripts?

Tags: gnu, ld

What are the common uses for custom linker scripts? When would I want to use one? What important things can I do with a custom linker script that I can't do with the default linker script? When do they provide advantages over the default linker script and what are those advantages?

I have in mind C++ if it affects the answer.

Comment: At the risk of not being very helpful overall, I would say - if you've read the `ld` documentation about custom linker scripts and didn't have anything pop into mind about how you might need to use them, then you most likely don't need them right now. In general they're useful only in rather specific circumstances often having to do with non-standard process address space layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The linker script can be considered a mapping from the "generic" data/code/uninitialized-data/read-only-constants/symbols sections in an ELF relocatable object file to the peculiarities required by the target system's executable loader.  In general, the "default" linker script for a toolchain and target OS is provided with the toolchain; custom linker scripts are used primarily in the embedded world, where there may not be an OS at all, or when writing low-level code such as bootloaders or OS kernels, as in those applications, you may not have the same guarantees (or any guarantees) as to "what goes where" vs. what an OS' executable loader provides for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the common uses, but in our case it is customization, because of a non standard os. We use it to set some symbols to identify special variables, which get another treatment while loading.